# How to add DLL to Qbs project

Tags: qt, dll, build, qbs

I have generated a DLL file.

I have a working Qbs project.

How can I add the DLL file to my project so that I can access the library's fonctions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to link to a library with files `theLibrary.lib` and `theLibrary.dll` you can try :

```
import qbs 1.0

Application {
     name: "AppName"
     files: "main.cpp"
     Depends { name: "cpp" }

     cpp.includePaths: [".","Path/To/include"]

     cpp.libraryPaths: ["Path/To/lib"]

     cpp.dynamicLibraries: "theLibrary"
}
```

Here you specify the library include path, path to the library and the library name.